# Linux Headless Server Audio Player RTP stream

Tags: linux, debian, headless, rtp, arm

I am streaming audio from a linux server (192.168.0.10) to a headless client using ffmpeg.

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT -acodec libmp3lame -ar 11025 --f rtp rtp://192.168.0.100:1234
```

On the headless client, I am trying to play the stream using vlc on the commandline.

```
cvlc rtp://192.168.0.10:1234
```

I get an error

```
inhibit interface error: Failed to connect to the D-Bus session daeon: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
```

Comment: Where are you trying to play the stream? Your receiving machine is headless! That is why you get this error. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: I rarely had a good experience with `cvlc` which is a headless/console VLC variant. Try using `mplayer` or `mpv` as both do great in headless mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed ffmpeg on the client and am now using ffplay without a display
like this:

`ffplay -nodisp rtp://192.168.0.10:1234`